# Prevent Query Parameters Submit with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a login page at my application and I don't want users to enter username/pass according to some conditions. I have these piece of code:

```
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">   
    if  (condition matches) {                   
        window.location.replace(newloginURL);       
    }                   
</script>
</head>
```

However, if user submits a query as like that:

```
https://mywebsite.com/lemma/j_security_check?j_username=uso&j_password=paso
```

He/She can enter via old login page. How can I prevent it via Javascript?

Comment: Why don't you use form to submit username and password?

Comment: I don't want users to login with this login page at some conditions.

Comment: Putting the username and password into a query string is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: redirect by force using javascript window.location='youUrl.html'

Comment: @Liam, yes it is bad. I want to limit some users who may enter old login credentials via query string and can login.

Comment: So why don't you add a redirect on the server so they can not hit the old login page? Also seems like a bad design to pass a password in a querystring.

Comment: @epascarello I should solve this problem via JavaScript due to I cannot edit Server/LB definitions. Old page accepts password in a query string and there is a new login page which I want users use it. However I cannot totally replace old login page due to some reasons.

Comment: I'm not clear how you want javascript to intercept a HTTP get. You enter the url into the location bar. Javascript can't intercept this process. Is that what you want Js, to intercept someone entering a URL into the location bar?

Comment: @Liam it works if user does not enter credentials via query string. There is also a login form at old login page. They may use that login page. If they want to use that login page my solution works. If they want to submit via query parameters it does not.

Comment: I don't understand what you asking. Sorry

Comment: If the user enters it via querystring, than it probably is too late if you are posting the form back to the same page to login. That request has already hit the server.

Comment: If the user enters via query string can I handle it at document.ready(), script tags within head tags etc?

Comment: If the server is processing it, document.ready is too late. The server already ran. Only thing you could do is detect it the querystring is there and send them to a log out page, but that is really not a solution. You really should be adjusting the serverside code and not trying to fix it with a band aid.

Comment: Can I detect query string at client side?